# Incomplete string version in DLL manifest

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005, manifest

Every time when I'm trying to load the .dll in my application, I'm getting an error.
I don't get any errors when I'm building it.
Here is a extracted manifest from my .dll, I don't see anything problematic here, except for the string version
Is this string version normal, if not how can I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.6195" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugMFC" version="8.0.." processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> version="8.0.."

No, that's not normal and most certainly will cause your program to fail to start.  This string comes from vc\atlmfc\include\mfcassem.h, it probably got damaged.  Do *not* edit the file to repair the damage, copy it from another machine.  That way updates will still work properly.